# C# Export DataGridView to Excel - Error with "SaveAs-Methode"

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, compiler-errors, export

I am currently working on a Little Project again (sorry i am kinda new to coding!) and I got stuck for some hours with a strange Problem (from my Point of view).

**What I want to do**

Save 2 `DataGridViews` to 1 Excel-File with 2 different Excel, Sheets.

#### My Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace project{
    public class ExcelWriter
    {

        public void WriteDataTableToExcel(DataGridView dgv_RawData, DataGridView dgv_ComputedData, string strFilePath, string Filename)
        {
            var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(true);

            System.Data.DataTable dt1 = (System.Data.DataTable)(dgv_RawData.DataSource);
            System.Data.DataTable dt2 = (System.Data.DataTable)(dgv_ComputedData.DataSource);

            AddExcelSheet(dt1, workbook);
            AddExcelSheet(dt2, workbook);

            workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\person\Desktop\test.xlsx");
            workbook.Close();
}
private static void AddExcelSheet(System.Data.DataTable dt, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = wb.Sheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet newSheet = sheets.Add();
        int iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            newSheet.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
        }

        int iRow = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            iRow++;
            // add each row's cell data...
            iCol = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                iCol++;
                newSheet.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Now I am getting the following 3 Errors:

> 1. No Overloaded Methode for "SaveAs" takes 1 Argument
> 2. No Overloaded Methode for "Close" takes 0 Arguments
> 3. No Overloaded Methode for "Add" takes 0 Arguments"

Sadly i have no clue how to solve this. I googled already for quite some time.. I first thought that some `using...` clauses are missing or that the Type isn't specified but nothing really worked...

I am thankful for every Little bit of help i can get!

Have a nice day

---

**Update:**
I got a little workarround where i save each file seperate as "csv" is there any way i can save both Datagridviews to 1 csv with different datasheets? Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
public void WriteDataTableToExcel(DataGridView dgv_RawData, DataGridView dgv_ComputedData, string strFilePath, string Filename)
    {

        string filename = "";
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv";
        sfd.FileName = "name.csv";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(filename);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("d" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            int columnCount = dgv_ComputedData.ColumnCount;
            string columnNames = "";
            string[] output = new string[dgv_ComputedData.RowCount + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
            {
                columnNames += dgv_ComputedData.Columns[i].Name.ToString() + ";";
            }
            output[0] += columnNames;
            for (int i = 1; (i - 1) < dgv_ComputedData.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    output[i] += dgv_ComputedData.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ";";
                }
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, output, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        }
```

Comment: As the error tells your methods are incomplete. Are you coming from the VB Side? In C# you have to match the given method signature.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I thought so, but i checked on MSDN about the requested type and for SaveAs for example all other informations are "optional" or am i wrong there? -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel

Comment: As i thought. Wrong Language. This is the VB/A documentation. C# has a stricter policy with method signatures. But you can use `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` for optional documented parameters.

Comment: You would only get these errors when you use a very old version of VS, VS2008 or less.  You really, really want to update, writing Office code in C# in that old version is painful and you'll have a hard time googling sample code.

Comment: @HansPassant yep this is the Problem, i was already wondering last time i used something like this it worked... Sadly i can NOT upgrade VS currently =/ is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: @Smartis thanks, so basically i have to fill in every value even if ist optional? so for example:  workbook.Close(System.Reflection.Missing.Value); ? -> still gives an error

Comment: I think i understood what you meant Smartis, i am trying =) thanks!

Comment: I found a Little Workaround though i save as "csv" now and i can not manage to save both Datagridviews to 1 document... Any ideas ?